# Как отобразить картинку через переменную

Tags: php, изображения

Есть директория на сервере с .png файлами со своими названиями.
Как через .php файл отображать картинку
Например:
site.ru/img.php?imgname=filename

filename название файла. А если нету такой картинки выводилось no-img.png

Comment: Конвертнуть её в `base64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот самый простой способ:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
if(!file_exists($url)){
    $url = '/img/no-img.png';
}

$url = '/img/' . $name . '.png';

echo "<img src='$url'>";
```

Естественно вам нужно подставить свой путь к директории, и заменить `echo` на тот вывод который вам необходим.